# Getting saved filename in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, save, google-chrome-app

I have a Chrome Packaged App that's a text editor. I've created a File Save dialog using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/FileSaver.js) but I have a problem.

- User Writes some text
- User clicks **Save** and saves file as 'myfile.txt' (I set the default as 'file.txt')
- User writes some more text
- User clicks **Save** again, and expects to see 'myfile.txt' in the dialog, but they just see 'file.txt'

So is there any way around this? Ideally I'd be able to work out what that filename was so I can save it in chrome's local storage along with the file they've been editing so that it remembers next time they start up.

I imagine I can't get the full path because of security problems - but is there a way to get just the filename? Is there some non-standard thing in Chrome Packaged Apps that would allow this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I imagine I can't get the full path because of security problems

Yes you can, and you just have to write `file.fullPath` to have it (as a string) when you're saving a file. Here is a simple example to save and get the path of a file:

```
function saveFile () {
    chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({
        type: "saveFile", 
        suggestedName: "file.txt"
    }, 
    function(savedFile) {
        // The code to save your file, here you can use savedFile.fullPath
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I used fullPath (or similar) on the normal save dialog, and that came up with a fake path - but presumably chrome.fileSystem gives you full access.